# Select SQL table names with no dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen scripts that can show the dependencies of an SQL table, but no script that can select the table names of tables with no dependencies.

Ideally, I would like to select all table names starting with Q (as seen below) and no dependencies in MSSQL, i.e.

```
SELECT t.NAME AS TableName
FROM sys.Tables t
where t.Name LIKE 'Q%' and no dependencies!
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dependencies"?

Comment: I'm referring to MSSQL dependencies (which I assumed were a standard SQL feature): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190624.aspx

Comment: @fithace . . . That is a feature in SQL Server Management Studio.  I think it refers to any triggers, stored procedures, user defined functions, views, and perhaps constraints.  I think the referred to documentation explains what to do:  use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should left join on sys.sql_expression_dependencies and grab the tables that aren't being referenced, something like:

```
SELECT t.NAME AS TableName
     FROM sys.Tables t
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies d ON d.referenced_id = t.object_id
    WHERE t.Name LIKE 'Q%'
      AND d.referenced_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
where T.TABLE_NAME like 'Q%'
and not exists (
    select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
    where TC.TABLE_NAME      = T.TABLE_NAME
    and   TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'   -- add conditions as needed
)
order by TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: This gives all tables, also those with a dependency.